# is there a programming language designed to express data combinations?

Tags: programming-languages, language-agnostic, linux, shell

Very often, when using the command line or just programming, you want to express some kind of combination that you end up using a `for` - which is often verbose.

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
    std::cout << "img_" << i << std::endl;

for f in *; do echo "$f"; done
```

I always wondered if there is some kind of language made to simplify this case? For example:

```
"mv img_[0~6] imgs"
```

Would translate to

```
mv img_0 imgs
mv img_1 imgs
mv img_2 imgs
mv img_3 imgs
mv img_4 imgs
mv img_5 imgs
```

`img_[0~1][0~1]` could work for `img_00, img_01, img_10, img_11`

`img_[x:0~2][x]` could work for `img_00, img_11, img_22`

Etc.

I'm not asking for this particular syntax, just if there is any kind of language/feature ever implemented with the purpose of expressing such combinations as easy as possible?

Comment: Ever hear about [apl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))? "It is concise, using symbols rather than words and applying functions to entire arrays without using explicit loops."

Comment: @Oded SE has eaten all of your time, except a little tiny bit left for snark? and in answer to the question: this wreaks of what people loved perl for.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: The term you're looking for is [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)

Comment: Haskell has a way to express [ranges](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#texas-ranges), pretty similar to the Bash syntax from choroba's answer.

Comment: @gnat Research, huh, so, what do you want me to talk about? Do you want me to turn this **question** into a book about my 10 years study of programming languages? Maybe you want to know about the language I implemented? Maybe you want a summary of Haskell, JavaScript, Python, Shell, C, C++ and so on, all of which don't have this feature? Or what do you want? Seriously? I don't even have patience for that kind of questioning anymore. My question is perfectly fine the way it is. Someone always complains. Regardless of the question, the votes, que answers. Not good enough. Someone always does it.

Comment: @Dokkat turn this question into a book hm... "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." ([Ask])

Comment: No that's not what... I... no... sighs...

Comment: @Dokkat - gnat's request isn't too far off base even though it's one of his canned comments for "this question needs more ..."  I can't quite tell if you're wanting a regex within a variable usage or if you're wanting on-the-fly matrix math.  Or both. You're already picking up one line answers which isn't good for  question quality.  Please [edit] and be a bit more clear in what you're seeking and why alternatives you have found haven't answered your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash, you can write

```
mv img_{0..5} imgs/
```

which is expanded by the shell to

```
mv img_0 img_1 img_2 img_3 img_4 img_5 imgs/
```

You can also use a character class:

```
mv img_[0-5] imgs/
```

which would only work for those files that already exist and match the expression, while the former expands to all the possibilities even if the files do not exist. The curlies can also pad the expanded number with zeros (`{001..030}`), reverse the order (`{z..a}`) or generate combinations (`{a..z}{0..5}`).

Comment: The brace expression can also do padding: `echo a{001..100}` and combinations: `echo {0,1}{0,1}{0,1}`

Comment: Oh, what a coincidence, I had no idea that existed and it is so similar to what I needed. Very cool, glad I've asked. Is there a way to use the same arg twice? img_{x:0..2}_{x} -> img_0_0 img_1_1 img_2_2

Comment: I think you are wrong about the zero padding though. It didn't work here.

Comment: @Dokkat: It might depend on the version of bash. Works in 4.2.24.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your immediate concern, bash can do some range-based actions on existing files.

```
$ ls
sample1.txt  sample2.txt  sample3.txt  sample4.txt  samples

$ mv sample[1-3].txt samples/

$ ls *
sample4.txt

samples:
sample1.txt  sample2.txt  sample3.txt
```

But there is a bigger trend at play here. [Array programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) tries to get away from explicit loops. It was really pushed by APL in the beginning and is now common in many mathematical languages like MATLAB or Mathematica. For example, I can add two numerical arrays with a simple

```
c = a + b
```

Likewise, [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) uses set notation to build an array. This is a common feature in many languages today, including Python and Haskell.

```
S = [2 * x for x in range(101) if x ** 2 > 3]
```

Within the realm of shell scripting, I can use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to execute a command on multiple inputs.

```
hg st | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | xargs rm     # delete my leftovers from Mercurial
```

In the world of databases, [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) can perform queries and updates on an entire column.

```
select sym from stocks where price < 20.0 order by sym;
```

And lastly, [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) obviates loops by defining an entity in terms of itself:

```
fac 0 = 1
fac x = x * fac (x-1)
```

So there are lots of examples where languages have gone away from explicit iterations in favor of declarative structures.

Comment: Recursion doesn't obviate looping. It just describes it in a different way.